# How to map one object to the other object in java

Tags: java, mapping

I am implementing a component where one component receive a message, it sends another message to Audit component so it can be audited.

Audit handler has model called AuditObject, and my component has MessageObject. Here is the code:

```
public final class AuditObject {
    private final Long id;
    private final String studyUid;
    private final AuditPatient patient;
    ...
}

public final class MessageObject {
    private final Long id;
    private final String studyUid;
    private final PatientObject patient;
    private final String accessorName;
    ...
}
```

AuditPatient and PatientObject have same variables.

I am trying to send it through amqp connection via jms message. I already have MessageGateway. So my code will look like this on my side.

```
public void send(MessageObject messageObject) {
    //translate MessageObject to AuditObject
    messageGateway.send(auditObject, endpoint);
}
```

What is the best way to translate(or map) MessageObject to AuditObject? Do I have to manually create each fields by assigning them? What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: you can create utility class and create a static method to convert from one object to another

Comment: Use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

Comment: If you are allowed to change the structure of your classes, then you could extract the common fields into a new (immutable) class and just set the field referencing an object of the new class in `AuditObject`

Answer (score 0):

Use static method in a class to convert one object to another and call it.

```
class ConvertObject {
   public static AuditObject convertMessageObjectToAudioObject(MessageObject messageObject) {
     AuditObject auditObject = new AuditObject();
     auditObject.setStudyUid(messageObject.getStudyUid());
     auditObject.setPatient(messageObject.getPatient());

     return auditObject;
   }
}

public void send(MessageObject messageObject) {
    AuditObject auditObject = ConvertObject.convertMessageObjectToAudioObject(messageObject);
    messageGateway.send(auditObject, endpoint);
}
```